# Jsoup parsing data-permalink

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

Hello stackoverflow community!

Let's assume i have a html code like this

```
<li class="river-block " id="123456" data-permalink="urlhere" data-shortlink="shortlinkhere" data-sharetitle="text">
```

I want to parse `data-shortlink` and i am trying to parse with code below

```
Document document= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements titlesOfPosts=document.getElementsByAttribute("data-shortlink");
```

and after that i seperate them using a foreach and i show them with Log.i() just to test if it is working but it is not working :( Thanks

Comment: Why isn't it working, what errors are you getting ?

Comment: It returns data-sharetitle's value instead of returning data-shortlink's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `Elements titlesOfPosts=document.getElementsByAttribute("data-shortlink");` returns a list of type `Element` of all the elements in your document that contain `data-shortlink` attribute.
If you want to do the following -

```
Elements titlesOfPosts=doc.getElementsByClass("river-block");
for (Element e : titlesOfPosts) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("data-shortlink"));
}
```

Loop thru. all the elements you've found and print the attribute's value.